# Where does composer install files to?

Tags: php, composer-php

Ok, so I am trying to learn composer. I installed composer using my server's SSH and ran this line:

```
php composer.phar require tomwalder/php-gds
```

And it did this:

```
Using version ^2.1 for tomwalder/php-gds
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing tomwalder/php-gds (v2.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%         
tomwalder/php-gds suggests installing google/apiclient (Allows you to use the JSON API Gateway/Datastore endpoints.
 Tested with 1.1.6)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Great, so now I look on my webserver and nothing seems to have changed. No files appear to be there. Where does composer install the files to?

Comment: A directory named 'vendor' under the directory with composer.lock. Be sure to include the autoload.php file in it

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies

Comment: How do I specify what folder to install to?

Answer (score 9):

Everything is a file called `vendor` in your current directory. Take a look at [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) to get what you're looking for

Answer (score 6):

The core point: a `vendor` directory is created in your webroot, with all the packages, but most importantly an `autoload.php` file. Include it from your main file with `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` and magically all classes are available now with the autoloaders.

The cool thing is that you can add an `autoload` section to your `composer.json` for your own project, and it will work identically.